# disable links of com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, hyperlink, itext, wildfly

The problem is the following, I have a method to create a pdf but when I add a text that contains a link and I create the pdf file it allows me the link to click, for security it cannot have links.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\ruta\\\\basepdf.pdf"))); 
Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSize(1),0,0,0,0);

BaseFont base =BaseFont.createFont("D:\\ruta\\fuente.ttf", BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font fonts = new Font(base, Float.parseFloat("40"),Font.BOLD, new BaseColor(255,0,0));

Paragraph parrafo= new Paragraph("https://www.youtube.com/", fonts);
Image imagen = Image.getInstance("D:\\ruta\\usuariosfondo.jpg");  

String base64Data = base64.substring(base64.indexOf(',') + 1);
byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(base64Data.getBytes());

Image imgQr = Image.getInstance(decoded);    

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);

document.open();
document.newPage();

parrafo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
parrafo.setFont(fonts);

ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
ct.setSimpleColumn(0,0,550,780);
ct.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
ct.addElement(parrafo); 
ct.go();

Float width = document.getPageSize().getWidth();    
Float height = document.getPageSize().getHeight();
imagen.scaleToFit(width, height);
imagen.setAbsolutePosition(0f, 0f);
imgQr.setAbsolutePosition(149f, 209f);
imgQr.scaleToFit(178.2992f, 178.2992f);
document.add(imagen);
document.add(imgQr);
//document.add(parrafo);    

document.close();   
String p=java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray());
```

text should appear with links only as text not enabled to launch the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pdf your code creates does not contain link annotations. So you don't make it clickable.

But it contains URLs! Certain pdf viewers, in particular Adobe Reader, automatically make any url they recognize clickable.

In case of Adobe Reader you can disable this "feature" in the settings.

If you don't have control over the settings of the viewers, simply don't put URLs into your pdfs. Or prevent them from being easily recognizable by a viewer, e.g. by rendering the URLs as bitmap images and using those images instead of the respective url text.

Comment: It is a public text, the idea is not to omit anything, there must be a way to control.

Comment: Unfortunately you have no control over viewer settings out there. Thus, you have to change URLs somehow. E.g. using images as described above. Alternatively you can describe URLs, writing http://host.domain as "http colon slash slash host dot domain". Or you can try and wrap the text with the url in a pattern. Unfortunately you have no control over Adobe, they might "improve" their Reader in such a way that it starts also recognizing your changed URLs as URLs. Furthermore, changing the URLs may restrict screen reader compatibility which in case of public text may be a no-go...

Comment: Yes, it is the only way that the restriction can be done without deleting data. Thanks as soon as I have the change, I publish it